# How to use a docker container for JRE in VSCode IDE?

Tags: java, docker, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, my IDE, I'm configure the [Language support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension with a "Java" docker container. Thus far I have been able to set up the runtime, however I didn't manage to point my IDE to the Java home directory of the docker container.

According to the extension's page, this is what I need to achieve in order to make the extension work:

> This JDK will be used to launch the Java Language Server. And by default, will also be used to compile your projects.
>
> The path to the Java Development Kit can be specified by the `java.home` setting in VS Code settings (workspace/user settings). If not specified, it is searched in the following order until a JDK meets current minimum requirement.
>
> - the `JDK_HOME` environment variable
> - the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable
> - on the current system path

## How I set up the runtime

As I already said, I manage to set up a runtime. This is how I did it:

1. Added a `java` binary for the docker container, in my case I put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   docker run \
        --name usr-local-bin-java \
        -i \
        --rm \
        --network=host \
        -w /root/project \
        -v "$PWD":/root/project \
        -v "$PWD"/.docker/mvn/cache:/root/.m2 \
        maven:3-jdk-8-slim \
        java "$@"

   exit $?
   ```

   I'm using a Maven image because I also needed Maven, which also includes Java. Of course a OpenJDK image could also have been used.
2. Added/updated my IDE's user `settings.json` with the following:

   ```
   "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "/usr/local/bin/java",
            "default": true
        }
   ],
   ```

## Where I am stuck at

So the last step I've in front of me, is to specify the path for `java.home`. But how will I do that if it's located in a docker container? Well the most obvious solution would be to mount the path in the docker container to my host. Unfortunately that won't work because the path I need is stored in the docker image, thus when I mount my host to the path then it will result in a empty directory.

To summarize this **won't work** (note: java home in my docker image is at `/usr/local/openjdk-8`):

1. Add the following argument to the `java` binary, to set up a volume mount:

   ```
   -v "$PWD"/.docker/java/jdk:/usr/local/openjdk-8 \
   ```
2. Add the `java.home` attribute to the `settings.json` config:

   ```
   "java.home": "${cwd}/.docker/java/jdk",
   ```

This will result in something like: "The `java.home` configuration doesn't point to a valid JDK".

Does anyone know: What are my options here? Can I point to directory in a interactive automatically removed docker container?

*PS: I don't want to install a JDK on my OS directly.*

**UPDATE #1: I managed to mount a volume from the docker container to my host**

1. Create a new docker volume:

   ```
   docker volume create openjdk
   ```
2. Add the volume mount arg to the the `java` binary:

   ```
   -v openjdk:/usr/local/openjdk-8 \
   ```
3. Run the binary:

   ```
   java -version
   ```
4. Add the `JDK_HOME` or `JAVA_HOME` variable to your bash env:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="$(docker inspect -f '{{ index .Mountpoint }}' openjdk)"
   ```
5. Reload the IDE and get errors...

   > Java 11 or more recent is required to run the Java extension. Please download and install a recent JDK. You can still compile your projects with older JDKs by configuring ['java.configuration.runtimes'](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#java.configuration.runtimes)

I even tried to set the `java.home` attribute to the mountpoint of the volume directly, which resulted in permission denied error, thus I `chmod +rx -R` my whole "var lib docker" directory (the place where the volumes are stored). Eventually the same error occurred as described in the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I guess I just figured it out how to accomplish it, but it's not really the best way to do it I would say. Because it basically is the same as downloading the jdk and placing it in a certain directory... anyway:

1. Create a docker volume to store the jdk in:

   ```
   docker volume create openjdk-15
   ```
2. Run a container with the jdk you want (needs to be Java 11 or more recent) and while doing so let it fill the volume you just created:

   ```
   docker run --rm -v openjdk-15:/usr/local/openjdk-15 openjdk:15-slim java -version
   ```
3. (optional) I like to symlink to the volume e.g.:

   ```
   sudo ln -s $(docker inspect -f '{{ index .Mountpoint }}' openjdk-15) /usr/local/lib/openjdk-15
   ```
4. Configure the extension in `settings.json`:

   ```
   "java.home": "/usr/local/lib/openjdk-15",
   "java.configuration.runtimes": [
     {
       "name": "JavaSE-15",
       "path": "/usr/local/lib/openjdk-15",
       "default": true
     }
   ]
   ```

So there is no need for a custom `java` binary what spins up a docker container. However you still will have to store the JDK-files on your OS directly.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be accomplished easily with the official [Dev Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension. You don't even need an existing image on your system, but that's supported as well if you want a customized container.

I was able to spin up a container with JDK through VS Code in a few minutes, and everything shows up in Docker Desktop as if you went through the whole process yourself.